# Navigation replaced by href=:javascript __doPostBack in Safari 6.2

Tags: 2007, browser-compatibility

This issue is only happening on safari 6.2 but all of the managed navigation on the site has been replaced with href=:javascript __doPostBack.

I looked through the console and there are not any javascript exceptions being thrown. In any other browser the __doPostBack is replaced with the correct URL.

I have searched the web extensively looking for a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the compatible browser file. I added

```
<browser refID="Safari60">
<controlAdapters>
    <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu" adapterType="" />
</controlAdapters>
</browser>
```

To C:\MOSS\Webs\Intranet\App_Browsers\compat.browser

Which fixed the issue.
Found the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25936427/aspmenu-in-safari-7-1-not-rendering-properly-in-sharepoint-2010

Answer (score -1):

In accordance with good practice, you're doing it right, but always a way to solve the world of WEB.

If not work using the tag 'a', do the following:

If you want to run a javascript function tries to use the tag 'p' with a property onclick="function ()"

Anything I am available to help you

Comment: Maybe something was lost in translation here but I have no idea what you are talking about.